# Using string.split() with a decimal - not working

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm trying to split a line of text into multiple parts. Each element of the text is separated by a period.
I'm using string.split("."); to split the text into an array of Strings, but not getting anywhere.

Here is a sample of the code:

```
String fileName = "testing.one.two";

String[] fileNameSplit = fileName.split(".");

System.out.println(fileNameSplit[0]);
```

The funny thing is, when I try ":" instead of ".", it works? How can I get it to work for a period?

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2755945/probelm-with-string-split-in-java?rq=1

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) accepts a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) (regex for short) and dot is a special char in regexes. It means "match all chars except newlines". So you must escape it with a leading backslash. But the leading backslash is a special character in java string literals. It denotes an escape sequence. So it must be escaped too, with another leading backslash. Like this:

```
fileName.split("\\.");
```

Comment: What's an example of a regex?

Comment: @Imray regular examples are patterns to match strings. You find them in all programming languages. Just google for a tutorial.

Answer (score 7):

Try this one: `fileName.split("\\.");`

Comment: Still not working. The output is _testing.one.two_ when I want it to be _testing_

Comment: @Imray  This is called escape sequence. '\\.' => It's a regex that matches a literal '.' character in Java. You escape '.' with one slash and escape that slash with a second slash.

Answer (score 5):

```
fileName.split(".");
```

should be

```
fileName.split("\\.");
```

**.** is special character and [split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) accepts regex. So, you need to escape the special characters.

> A character preceded by a backslash `(\)` is an escape sequence and has
>   special meaning to the compiler. Please read this [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html).

Answer (score 4):

It's because the argument to `split` is a regular expression, and `.` means basically any character. Use `"\\."` instead of `"."` and it should work fine.

The regular expression for a literal period (as opposed to the any-character `.`) is `\.` (using the `\` escape character forces the literal interpretation).

And, because it's within a string where `\` already has special meaning, you need to escape *that* as well.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the "." character because split accept regular expressions and the . means any character, so for saying to the split method to split by point you must escape it like this:

```
String[] array = string.split('\\.');
```

Answer (score 1):

The [split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) takes in param a [regex](http://www.coderanch.com/t/324803/java/java/Java-regular-expression-dot-pattern)

Try.using

```
String[] fileNameSplit = fileName.split("\\.");
```