# I would like to extract the quadrants of an IP address

Tags: java, networking

So my program that I am creating is going to calculate the subnet of an IP address that is given. It is being written in java.
The program asks for the IP address that will always be given in the form 255.255.255.255. The plan is to separate a part of the string, then wrap it into an integer.

I need to extract each of the 4 quadrants as separate integers.
The trick I can't figure out is how to do this when the IP looks more like 192.168.1.20.
How would I be able to do this and get reliable results.

User input : 192.168.205.16

Created Variables :

Quadrant1 : 192

Quadrant2 : 168

Quadrant3 : 205

Quadrant4 : 16

Comment: Use the **String.split()** method. `String[] quadrants = input.split("\\.");`

Comment: My guess is that it's coming in as a string. In which case just split it on the periods and convert it to whatever.

Comment: The proper terminology is `octets`, not `quadrants`. They are called `octets` because each represents eight bits of the 32-bit address. Convert the four octets to a 32-bit integer, mask it with the network mask, then convert back to the dotted-decimal notation. That will give you the network address in the text format.

Comment: Ya...what he said...but in reality you can call it **dirtyUnderwear** if you want. ;)

Comment: @DevilsHnd, my comment was for the OP, not your comment. I hoped for a little education with the comment.

Comment: @RonMaupin haha thanks guys, I actually did know they were octets but i started the project on day 1 when I had no idea, simple refactor coulda solved it I suppose :P late reply, thanks none the less

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] ipSplit = userInput.split("\\.");
Integer q1 = Integer.valueOf(ipSplit[0]);
...
```

etc..
edits:  my bad, regex for the split string, and array of strings rather than list of strings

Comment: meh array of Strings vs List of Strings... sue me

Comment: I tested it and it seems  its just throwing an array exception, where the (ipSplit[0]); or whatever number is used is out of bounds... Any suggestions?

Comment: `split` takes a regular expression as its argument, so `.` is not what you think see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2755949/2310289

Comment: This answer does not add anything that was not written in @DevilsHnd commetn above

Comment: Maybe it will help if you just see what is there so far... I put it into a separate class
http://collabedit.com/yjtr8

Comment: Technically it does, @scary, as evidenced by the Integer q1 bit

Comment: Got it fixed, working code is in the link above! Thanks guys, love you all <3

Comment: @dbs.83 OK I agree with that.